# Отследить процесс загрузки файлов с базы данных с использованием fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch

У меня есть карточки товаров, которые заполняются с базы данных. При загрузке страницы, хочу сделать показ скелета этих карточек, а после загрузки всех файлов показать контент (фото, текст вместо скелета), как помощи  fetch в JavaScript отследить или процесс загрузки или конец загрузки?

Comment: Сделайте так как хотите, что вас останавливает? [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) просто выполняет запрос на сервер, когда сервер ответит, удалите секлет и поместите на его место html с фотками.

Comment: просто у меня карточки генерируются в зависимости от количества в базе данных, поэтому я думал можно через Фетч запросить данные, создать скелетоны и потом уже когда все файлы подгрузятся закинуть их вместо карточек

Comment: А что за файлы должны подгрузиться? И зачем вам вообще всё это? Какая ваша конечная цель? Обычно во всяких [SPA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) это делается так: 1) отображается скелетон, 2) стартует загрузка данных с бэка через fetch, 3) когда данные загрузились, меняете скелетон на карточки с данными из бд

Comment: понял, тогда сделаю статическое количество скелетов и вместо них поставлю карточки по окончанию загрузки, спасибо большое